# NodeJS find if file or folder is hidden

Tags: node.js

What the title says, how do I find if a file or folder is hidden using NodeJS? Please don't just refer me to some npm package that's suppose to do that (been there, done that), only answer if you have working code and show that code. Thanks.

Comment: Share the code you wrote. Share what your expectations were and how they failed. Usually all you have to do is to see if the file or directory starts with a `.`

Answer (score -1):

hidden files are already displayed when reading for exemple a dir they just have a dot in front of them

```js
//Require fs (node filesystem)
var fs = require("fs");
//Read folder syncronously with fs (node filesystem)
var folder = fs.readdirSync("/path/to/folder/")
//Print to the console a stringified version of the array returned by folder read
console.log(JSON.stringify(folder))
```

Exemple of what could be printed to the console:

```
["file", ".hiddenfile"]
```

As you can see the hidden files are displayed with a dot (".") at the start of their name: "hiddenfile" => ".hiddenfile"

Comment: “*they just have a dot in front of them*” This is a UNIX-specific convention and in no way is a cross-platform solution. Windows does not hide files beginning with a `.`.

Comment: Then use this npm package as so:
```bash
npm i is-hidden-file
```
Then write this:
```javascript
var isHiddenFile = require("is-hidden-file").isHiddenFile;

var check = isHiddenFile("path/to/file");
console.log(check); //true or false
```